# Importing a bunch of names in Lua

Tags: lua

In my script I follow the practice of "importing" functions from another module. So I have code similar to the following at the start of my script:

```
local some_function = assert(require("utils").some_function)
local another_func = assert(require("utils").another_func)
local yet_another = assert(require("utils").yet_another)
local and_another = assert(require("utils").and_another)
```

But this chunk of code is not quite readable.

(The `assert()` is there to guard against spelling mistakes in the function names.)

I know that I can easily write my own function, say `require_names()`, and turn the above code into:

```
local some_function, another_func, yet_another, and_another
  = require_names("utils", { "some_function", "another_func", "yet_another", "and_another" })
```

This looks *much* better. Still, it's not optimal: there's redundancy in this code: the names of the functions repeat twice.

Is there a way for me to write my `require_names()` so that it doesn't have the redundancy problem?

Or, do you you have any ideas for solving the readability problem in some other way?

(I need solutions that run on both Lua 5.1 and 5.2)

Comment: `setmetatable(_G, {__index = require"utils"})`

Comment: Egor's solution is fine as long as you only use one module. You cannot inherit from two modules at the same time with that solution.

Comment: In Lua 5.2, you can do `_ENV=require"utils"` and all global variables will be resolved in `utils`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only a subset of what is in utils module, yet only create locals, then you can't. Other answers give you the whole utils module, in that case I don't see why not just use `require 'yourmodule'`. If you can relinquish locals, then:

```
function require_names(modName, objNames)
    for i,v in ipairs(objNames)  do
         _G[v] = assert(require(modName)[v]) 
    end
end
```

works in both 5.1 :

```
> print(setn)
nil
> print(insert)
nil
> require_names("table", {"setn", "insert"})
> print(setn)
function: 005F7910
> print(insert)
function: 005F7890
```

The only non-globals option is to put what you want in a local table, to get only the subset you need:

```
function require_names(modName, objNames)
    local mod = {}
    for i,v in ipairs(objNames) do
         mod[v] = assert(require(modName)[v]) 
    end
    return mod
end

local utils = require_names("utils", { 'a', 'b' })
utils.a = asdfasf
print(utils.b)
```

However, the only benefit of above compared to `local utils=require 'utils'` is that it documents what you module is going to use from the required module. But it is a little noisy with all the quotes and braces.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
local u = require 'utils'
```

Then use it like this:

```
u.some_function(...)
```

This is very easy to type and very obvious.

If you really need locals, then I would not use a single function called `require_names` but two: the regular `require` + `extract`. Here's `extract`

```
local function extract(t, keys)
  local values = {}
  for i=1, #keys do values[i] = t[keys[i]] end
  return unpack(values)
end
```

Usage:

```
local utils = require 'utils'
local some_function, another_func, yet_another, and_another = 
  extract(utils, { "some_function", "another_function", "yet_another", "and_another"})
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does require+extract seem more elegant to you than a single function? (Intuitively I see that it's more elegant but I'd like to hear your way of thinking.)

Comment: I wrote about that some time ago. [Here're my thoughts](http://kikito.github.io/blog/2012/03/16/small-functions-are-good-for-the-universe/)